# Swift - Display two separate images in 2 UIImageViews in 1 ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I would like to display two images on one viewcontroller selecting them from the camera roll,

I have managed to get to the camera roll to be able to select them but when I select one image it places them in both UIImageViews.

I want to be able to display two different images in the UIImageView.

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //handle media here i.e. do stuff with photo

        print("imagePickerController called")


        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] {
        profileImage.image = chosenImage as? UIImage

        let user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 1)
        if (profileImageData != nil)
        {
            let profileFileObject = PFFile(data: profileImageData!)
            user.setObject(profileFileObject!, forKey: "profilePicture")
            }
        }
```

Up to here I can select one image and save it to Parse successfully, but when I try and add the other code for the other UIImageView, like this:

```
            if let chosenCoverImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] {
            coverImage.image = chosenCoverImage as? UIImage

            let coverUser: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
            let coverImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImage.image!, 1)
            if (coverImageData != nil)
            {
                let coverFileObject = PFFile(data: coverImageData!)
                coverUser.setObject(coverFileObject!, forKey: "coverPicture")
                }}
            }
```

That second part of code doesn't seem to work though, basically it shows the same image in both UIImageViews, what I think I need is a second

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
}
```

But that oviously isn't possible in the same swift file.

Any idea's on how I could achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Here's my full imagePickerConytoller code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //handle media here i.e. do stuff with photo

        print("imagePickerController called")


        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        profileImage.image = chosenImage

        let user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 1)
        if (profileImageData != nil)
        {
            let profileFileObject = PFFile(data: profileImageData!)
            user.setObject(profileFileObject!, forKey: "profilePicture")
            }

        let chosenCoverImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        coverImage.image = chosenCoverImage

        let coverUser: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let coverImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImage.image!, 1)
        if (coverImageData != nil)
        {
            let coverFileObject = PFFile(data: coverImageData!)
            coverUser.setObject(coverFileObject!, forKey: "coverPicture")
            }

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.profileImage.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.grayColor()

        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }


        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And here is how I get them from Parse in my ViewDidLoad :

```
if (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profilePicture") != nil)
        {
            let userImageFile:PFFile = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            })
        }

        if (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("coverPicture") != nil)
        {
            let userCoverFile:PFFile = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("coverPicture") as! PFFile
            userCoverFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.coverImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            })
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in the upload to parse and not the way you assign the images to the `UIImageView` after they've been assigned?

Comment: Are the first two code fragments above contained in the same imagePickerController? 
Unless there's some missing code, it is going to do the same thing twice - with the same image.  You just need a variable in your class to track which image you're working on, and put the image in profileImage or coverImage

Comment: Hey @Russell yes they're in the same imagePickerController, can that work?

Comment: yes it will work - but you have to remember that you only get to the imagePickerController when you have already made your selection.

What you need to do is call that function twice - once for each type of image, and you need something to keep a track of which image you're working on

Comment: @Russell I have updated my code above, the ViewDidLoad and my full imagePickerController code.

Comment: @Russell actually after your comment, I just had another look, I dont think I'm telling the code I post above which button is being pressed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't going to be complete, but will have the key parts you will need

```
class ResponsePhotoController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    var imageType : Int = 0  // use this to track the image type
                             // 0 for profile
                             // 1 for cover
```

in your code to go get the profile image

```
imageType = 0
```

and then when you go get the cover image

```
imageType = 1
```

and then in the imagePickerController

```
if imageType == 0
{
    // set up the profile picture
}
else
{
    // set up the cover image
}
```

Comment: sorry - I don't know anything about Parse!  My example was using CoreData.

Sounds like you need to post a separate question

Comment: haha my bad, I got you mixed up with another Russell on here, didn't realise!!

Answer (score 0):

yo can use use a string "CameraFor" here on camera button click. 
set string on profile camera button click  "ImageForProfile"
set string on Cover camera button click  "ImageForCoverPhoto".

class ResponsePhotoController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    imageType : Int = 0  // use this to find image type public class variable

```
if CameraFor == "ImageForProfile" {
   //set image here for profile

 } 
else {
   //set image here for ImageForCoverPhoto 
     }
```

}